# Change $primary-color for materialize in Rails 6 project

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, webpack, materialize, ruby-on-rails-6

I just got finished adding Materialize CSS to my Rails 6 project using this great guide:
https://medium.com/@guilhermepejon/how-to-install-materialize-css-in-rails-6-0-0-beta2-using-webpack-347c03b7104e

The general styles have updated and things are great until I want to change the `$primary-color` sass variable. I see the `<nav>` is styled to the default red color when my `app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss` looks like this:

```
$primary-color: color("blue", "lighten-2") !default;
@import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize';
```

I have used `gem 'materialize-sass'` with great success in the past with a Rails 5 project, but Rails 6 is new to me.

With my success using the gem my `app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss` would look like this:

```
@import "materialize/components/color-variables";
$primary-color: color("blue", "lighten-2") !default;
@import 'materialize';
```

`materialize/components/color-variables` is not a part of the webpack package and if I try to import a scss file copy of https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/master/sass/components/_variables.scss then I get an error like this which seems to show a disconnect with the JS of the materialize package.

```
$primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%) !default;
                     ^
      Argument `$color` of `lighten($color, $amount)` must be a color
      in
```

Any thoughts on how to change the sass variables like `$primary-color` to override for Materialize CSS in a Rails 6 project? :)

Answer (score 0):

Actually you are just importing the colors. You should import the variables also by adding in top of your CSS this code
`@import "materialize-css/sass/components/_color-variables";`
`@import "materialize-css/sass/components/_variables";`

always think of searching the file in github repository then open it and look for the variables to override
[link1](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/sass/components/_variables.scss)
[link2](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/blob/v1-dev/sass/components/_color-variables.scss)